# What do parentheses around a closure mean?

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand how this custom Navigation bar / Paging View works, found [here](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift). What is tripping me up when I went through the README was setting up the tinder-like custom behavior:

```
// Tinder Like
controller?.pagingViewMoving = ({ subviews in
    for v in subviews {
        var lbl = v as UIImageView
        var c = gray

        if(lbl.frame.origin.x > 45 && lbl.frame.origin.x < 145) {
            c = self.gradient(Double(lbl.frame.origin.x), topX: Double(46), bottomX: Double(144), initC: orange, goal: gray)
        }
        else if (lbl.frame.origin.x > 145 && lbl.frame.origin.x < 245) {
            c = self.gradient(Double(lbl.frame.origin.x), topX: Double(146), bottomX: Double(244), initC: gray, goal: orange)
        }
        else if(lbl.frame.origin.x == 145){
            c = orange
        }
        lbl.tintColor = c
    }
})
```

I don't understand why there are parentheses around the closure that is being set to the controller?.pagingViewMoving property.

When I look in the [SLPagingViewSwift.swift](https://github.com/StefanLage/SLPagingViewSwift/blob/master/SLPagingViewSwift/SLPagingViewSwift.swift) file, the .pagingViewMoving property is set to this alias:

```
public typealias SLPagingViewMoving = ((subviews: [UIView])-> ())
```

What are the extra set of parentheses doing outside the function type?

Answer (score 5):

In this case the parentheses are purely for clarity and are unnecessary. Its just like saying `let a = (2 + 2)`. Although this should not be confused with closures provided as arguments in the following case.

If a function itself takes an argument which is a closure, the closure is simply within the parentheses thats contain the functions parameters.

So thanks to the syntax higher order functions that take a closure as their last (or only) argument that be represented in two ways - inside the argument parentheses or as whats known as a trailing closure. Consider the following function:

```
func foo(bar: (Int -> Int)) {...}
```

it can be called in two ways - first with the closure in the parentheses like so:

```
foo({(i) in i + 2})
```

or as a trailing closure:

```
foo {(i) in i + 2}
```